# What is difference between beacon and normal ble detection in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

when beacon is more useful in ble application in android?
What are the benefits to use beacon ,is i know we can customize background scan rate. but using normal ble also we can change background scan rate by using  SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER and other flags. both will decrease the scan period. 
can anyone explain these

Comment: What do you mean when you say "using beacon"

Comment: "using beacon" i mean using  Android Beacon Library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beacons as a specialized version of a Bluetooth LE device.  They are designed as transmit-only devices that simply send out a unique identifier at regular intervals, typically at 1-10 Hz.  Beacons send out these identifiers using Bluetooth LE Advertisements, a feature which is a relatively small subset of the Bluetooth 4.0 specification.

Beacon-specific Android libraries like the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) are designed to focus on the use case of detecting Bluetooth LE beacons as opposed to doing more general purpose Bluetooth LE operations.  **A beacon library adds logic on top of built-in Android BLE Scanning** including:

- Parsing of beacon identifiers from raw BLE advertisements, based on different beacon formats (Eddystone, AltBeacon, iBeacon, etc.)
- Event-driven APIs to tell you when a specific beacon identifier pattern is first seen and then stops being seen.
- Regular callbacks (e.g. once per second) telling you a list of which beacons are visible.
- Distance estimates to beacons.
- Automatic switching of scan intervals as the app switches from the foreground to the background.
- Automatic wakeup of the app when beacons are detected.

While it is possible to do all of the above with the lower-level Bluetooth LE APIs in Android, you have to write a lot of code to build these features yourself.  **Using a beacon library allows you to focus on your App's business logic and leave the complexities of dealing with the beacon parsing and detection functions to somebody else.**

Full disclosure:  I am the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project.

Comment: Thank you @davidgyoung !!  " Automatic wakeup of the app when beacons are detected".  can you please explain little bit about this , i mean How it is working for android application.is it scanning in background service ? how it is usefull for battery life of mobile ?

Comment: See here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html